# Nagios Notification Escalation

Tags: nagios

I've got Nagios configured properly, and I'm looking to do some (minorly) strange things with notifications.

What we want to do is have the first three notifications fire off 5 minutes apart, then if nobody responds, the next 3 at 30 minutes apart, and beyond that, 60 minutes apart. I've got all this running properly as well.

The last part of what I want to do is where the problem occurs. I want these repeated notifications to NOT send overnight (between 23:00 and 08:00), but for all NEW notifications, those SHOULD send. What's happening is that for the third escalation (the 60-minute one) works fine up until 23:00, and then it reverts to the 5-minute level because it's outside the `escalation_period` I've set.

I thought I could get around it by setting another escalation period that runs during the 'nighttime' hours, but that didn't work either. Here's what I've got for the config:

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       mercury
        service_description             ROB_TEST2
        check_command                   check_pop
        contact_groups                  robonly
        }

define serviceescalation{
        host_name                       mercury
        service_description             ROB_TEST2
        first_notification              3
        last_notification               5
        notification_interval           30
        contact_groups                  robonly
        }
define serviceescalation{
        host_name                       mercury
        service_description             ROB_TEST2
        first_notification              6
        last_notification               9999
        notification_interval           60
        contact_groups                  robonly
        escalation_period               daytime
        }
define serviceescalation{
        host_name                       mercury
        service_description             ROB_TEST2
        first_notification              6
        last_notification               9999
        notification_interval           60
        contact_groups                  nobody
        escalation_period               nighttime
        }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have any contact groups or users defined on the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would work if you specified the time period on the contact.  Define the contact twice: once with notifications at night, and again with notifications only during the day.

```
define service{
    use                             generic-service
    host_name                       mercury
    service_description             ROB_TEST2
    check_command                   check_pop
    contacts                        rob_daytime, rob_nighttime
    }

define serviceescalation{
    host_name                       mercury
    service_description             ROB_TEST2
    first_notification              3
    last_notification               5
    notification_interval           30
    contacts                        rob_daytime, rob_nighttime
    }

define serviceescalation{
    host_name                       mercury
    service_description             ROB_TEST2
    first_notification              6
    last_notification               9999
    notification_interval           60
    contacts                        rob_daytime
    }

define contact{
    contact_name                    rob_daytime
    service_notification_period daytime
    ...
    }

define contact{
    contact_name                    rob_nighttime
    service_notification_period nighttime
    ...
    }
```

This should give you a good night's sleep even though an escalation has been running for a few days.

*Note*: I haven't tested this myself ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Be *very* careful should you decide to limit anything by last_notification. At least with the versions I know, going into escalation does not reset that counter, which is relatively harmless. Transitions from WARN to CRIT also will not - which tends to end up deadly.